# Slack update is ready to install. is asking repeatedly for my password

Tags: macos

[image]

Does not matter if I cancel of Add Helper this comes back.
It's in a seemingly endless loop. Any ideas how to deal with this incessant prompting?

Comment: It may need Full Disk Access to be able to do that. Can't test, don't have Slack.

Comment: I fail to see why a messenger wants Full Disk Access short of an explanation it's real purpose is to spy on the user.

Comment: It's likely to depend on *where* it needs to install the helper.

Comment: That pic looks super spammy. I’d delete your Slack app and reinstall from Mac App Store, or slack.com.

Comment: @jimtut done that. Thanks! Feel free to post as an answer for upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Moving this from a comment to a full answer. That pic doesn’t look legitimate, something seems “off” (spammy). Delete the current Slack app and just reinstall.